# Change default skeletons for RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio has a wonderful set of skeletons for packages and Rmd documents. But, I'd like to know if it's possible to change the defaults to a "skeleton" of your own design. If, like me, you package your research for yourself/clients, you quickly find yourself deleting and copying the same work over and over.

I suppose there are two related questions here:

- Can you change the default package skeleton?
- Can you change the default Rmd skeleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize it then, but I was actually looking for a custom format. The details of which are documented extensively on the rmarkdown rstudio site.

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_custom_formats.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no supported way to do this. However, the skeletons are stored as ordinary files in your filesystem, so there's nothing stopping you from modifying them. For instance, if you're on the Mac, this file provides the default Rmd skeleton:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/templates/r_markdown_v2.Rmd
```

On Windows, it's here:

```
C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\templates\r_markdown_v2.Rmd
```